# How can I prevent a ceiling fan light kit from wobbling?

Tags: repair, light-fixture

I have a ceiling fan with a single light bulb attachment below the fan.  This light bulb socket is loose and wiggles on the unit.  Sometimes I can get the light bulb inserted in the socket in a certain way and it works okay.  Other times I cannot get the bulb to work at all.  Any I don't want to spend a fortune on just fixing this socket.

Comment: Not enough info, but reattaching or replacing a socket is a cheap and easy fix in most lamps, if you know what you're doing with house voltage.

Comment: Yeah, fan kits are cheap (under ten bucks). It might be worth starting fresh. Otherwise, post a photo or model information.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to take the light or light kit apart. Typically they are locked into place on the wire shaft & quite wobbly & loose.

But, if this has gotten looser & looser, then you should be able to tighten a nut or 2 on the wire shaft to get everything back to solid.

Be conscious of the loosening in the future by holding the light socket with 1 hand while swapping out the bulb with your other hand. You can also put a drop of any glue on the threads to keep it tight a good long while.